# Show that if $x \geq y$, then $(e^{\frac{x}{2}}-e^{\frac{y}{2}})^2 \leq \frac{(x-y)^2}{8}(e^x+e^y)$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, exponential-function

I tried to naively fix $y$ and then study the sign of

$$f:x \mapsto \frac{(x-y)^2}{8}(e^x+e^y)-(e^{\frac{x}{2}}-e^{\frac{y}{2}})^2 $$

but it gets ugly pretty fast.

Comment: I tried using a substitution but i got stuck: if you look at $x=y$ then you get: $0\le0$ which is true, so now look at $x>y$. We could try saying if:
$$X=e^{x/2},Y=e^{y/2}$$
then:
$$(X-Y)^2\le\frac{(2\ln X-2\ln Y)^2}{8}(X^2+Y^2)$$
which we can simplify to:
$$(X-Y)^2\le\frac 12\ln^2\left(\frac XY\right)(X^2+Y^2)$$
now since $x>y$,$X>Y$ so $X/Y>0$. If we rearrange a bit we get:
$$\frac XY\ge\exp\left(\sqrt{\frac{2(X-Y)^2}{X^2+Y^2}}\right)$$
$$\frac{(X-Y)^2}{X^2+Y^2}=\frac{X^2+Y^2-2XY}{X^2+Y^2}=1-\frac{2XY}{X^2+Y^2}$$
and since it can be easily shown that $2XY\le X^2+Y^2$ we can say:

Comment: $$0\le\frac{2(X-Y)^2}{X^2+Y^2}\le2$$
and so:
$$1\le\exp\left(\sqrt{\frac{2(X-Y)^2}{X^2+Y^2}}\right)\le e^{\sqrt{2}}$$
now we know that:
$$\frac XY=e^{(x-y)/2}$$
so we have:
$$e^{(x-y)/2}\ge e^{\sqrt{2}}$$

Comment: thanks for the attempt. This change of variable does seem to simplify the inequality a bit, but it looks like the inequality $\exp\left(\sqrt{\frac{2(X-Y)^2}{X^2+Y^2}}\right)\le e^{\sqrt{2}}$ is not sufficient to conclude since $e^{(x-y)/2} > e^{\sqrt{2}}$ is not true as soon as $x-y  < 2\sqrt{2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}$
$\newcommand{\e}{\mathrm{e}}$

Let $f$ be a nonnegative convex function such as $f(t)=\e^{t/2}$. Then the Hermite-Hadamard inequality says that

$$\int_y^xf(t)\d t \leq (x-y)\left(\frac{f(y)+f(x)}{2}\right)$$

and the generalized mean inequality says that
$$\frac{f(y)+f(x)}{2}\leq \sqrt{\frac{f(y)^2+f(x)^2}{2}}$$

so that
$$\left(\int_y^xf(t)\d t\right)^2\leq (x-y)^2\left(\frac{f(y)^2+f(x)^2}{2}\right)\text{.}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let
\begin{align}
 f(t)&=\frac{t^2}8-1 + \text{sech}\frac t2\\
f’(t)&= \frac t4-\frac12 \tanh\frac t2\text{sech}\frac t2\\
f’’(t)&= \frac14(1+\text{sech} \frac t2 -2 \text{sech}^3 \frac t4)\\
&= \frac14[(1-\text{sech}^3 \frac t2)+ \text{sech} \frac t2
(1-\text{sech}^2 \frac t2)]>0
\end{align}
Note $f(0)=f’(0) =0$. Thus, $f(t)$ is convex with the minimum value $0$, meaning $f(t)\ge0$. Then, substitute $t=x-y$ into $f(t)$ above to get
$$f(x-y) = \frac{(x-y)^2}8-1+\frac{2e^{\frac{x-y}2}}{e^{x-y}+1} \ge0
$$
and rearrange the inequality to obtain
$$(e^{\frac{x}{2}}-e^{\frac{y}{2}})^2 \leq \frac{(x-y)^2}{8}(e^x+e^y)$$